# What should I replace small structs with in Java?

Tags: java, oop, struct, maps, idioms

I am building a mapping app in Java, and I have a question about passing around small objects. Say I want to represent the area that the window is showing as a rectangle, and I want to query which tiles are inside that rectangle so I know which ones to load. In C++, I would have just made a `Rect` struct and included a `tileInRect` method. The most direct translation to Java would be something like:

```
class Rect {
    float x, y, width, height;

    public boolean tileInRect(Tile t) {
        // yada yada
    }
}

class MyProgram {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        while (windowIsOpen()) {
            // event loop
            // render map
            Rect r = getVisibleRect();
            for (Tile t : tiles) {
                if (r.tileInRect(t)) {
                    // etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this feels sort of icky to me, since I will be presumably making a new Rect every frame. Is there a better, more canonical way to represent these lightweight objects in Java? I don't really want to write helper methods like `tileInRect(Tile t, int rect_x, int rect_y, int ...` since that seems like just an absurd amount of parameter passing. Thanks!

Comment: Class is the best option, try Collection if it can meet your needs.

Comment: you could also reuse the same rect instance between frames and just update its fields. either way this is the correct design.

Comment: Making a new rect should not cost you that much. The Java code is never duplicated, the JVM will only allocate some control structures to track the instance of the class and the storage required for x,y etc.

Comment: Objects are much cheaper than you realize, is the thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rect class is the good way to go.

If you have to create a lot of these objects but you only need them once, just reuse the same object for every call by updating his attributes.

Comment: OK, thanks! @James mentioned that making new rects every frame shouldn't be that costly so I think I'll go with this method.

Answer (score 0):

One may use either an immutable class type or a mutable class type.  The ideal representation in .NET would be an exposed-field structure (which would behave as mutable in most of those contexts where it should, and as immutable in most those contexts where it should), but since Java doesn't support any such concept one must go with either a mutable class or an immutable class, recognizing the pros and cons of each.

A mutable class has the advantage that if one has the only extant reference to an object, one wishes to have an object which is different in some way, and one will no longer need the old version of the object, one can simply change the appropriate piece of the object without having to create a new object, and without having to copy or otherwise do anything with the parts of the object one doesn't want to change.  A mutable class has the disadvantage that because such mutations are only safe if one has the only extant reference to an object, one cannot safely share references to objects with other code; one must instead either create new objects and give those to the other code, or else copy the data from one's own objects into objects supplied by the other code.

An immutable class has the advantage that references to an object may be freely shared with outside code without worrying about what that code might do to the object (since the object is immutable, outside code *can't* do anything to it!).  Unfortunately, while it's great that outside can't do anything to the object, immutability also means even the logical "owner" of an object can't do anything with it.  If one has an object and wishes to have one that is different in some way, one must generate a whole new object which is different in that way.  Even if in fact nobody anywhere in the universe would ever care if the old object were modified, there's generally no way by which code can know that.

If code will generate modified forms of objects more often than it will exchange them with other code, mutable class types may be preferred.  If objects will be passed around a lot, but production of new forms will be relatively infrequent, immutable class types may be preferred.  Note that it's possible (and common) to wrap a mutable class type in an immutable class type which holds the only reference to the "mutable" object anywhere in the universe, and which neither mutates that object nor exposes the reference to anything that might do so.  I don't know if there's a term for objects of mutable types which will in fact never mutate, but it's frequently a useful pattern (a prime example would be `String`; arrays in Java are mutable, but because a `String` never mutates its character array and never exposes it to outside code, there's no way the sequence of characters in a `String` object can ever change.